# Xcode error "Could not create application container"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to build my first iPhone application.  I have a license that I just downloaded and installed along with a Provisioning Profile.

Earlier I received the error of "no matching provisioning profile".  This was solved by refreshing from the developer portal (in Organizer, Editor->Refresh from Developer Portal).

Now, I try to compile, and I get the message "Build Succeeded", but afterwards I get (twice) a popup with the error "Could not create application container".

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all profiles and click refresh again. Also check if build settings are using right profilers.